# Selenium IDE Field Highlight on Screenshot

Tags: testing, selenium, plugins, ide

Does anyone know a way to take a website screenshot with highlighted affected fields using Selenium IDE?

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is not generally a good fit for stackoverflow because it attracts opinionated answers.  You might consider http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation i'm new here so i did not know that, i've moved and edited the question.